# Laravel Polymoprhic Associations

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

Can someone help me understand if this is correct? I am trying to define relationships between data objects.
All these things are schedulable appointments.

Polymorphic table -> appointments with colums schedulable_id, schedulable_type, start_date, end_date.

Then have the following objects:
Services, Courses

Both of these are schedulable, but you could schedule multiple services for 1 appointment. On both of these you can have multiple users for each appointment that is schedulable, and can schedule multiple appointsment for the same object.

Is this heading the right direction? In the future I would like to be able to add more "schedulable" objects to the database.

Comment: Seems like you have 1:N relationship in your database but what you need is M:N

Comment: Okay that's what I was trying to wrap my head around. So right now I'm headed down the many to many polymorphic associations.
tables: appointments, schedulable, services, courses

Comment: The question of many-to-many is: Can 1 service have many appointments AND can 1 appointment have many services? If the answer is yes, you have many to many. To me it sounds like you do. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations, if you are still trying to figure this out. I think you need a 'appointments' table, an 'appointmentables' table, a 'services' table and a 'courses' table.